# I'm posting a tiny part of my code that is giving me an error. Only two lines need to be fixed to avoid "not a number' error

Tags: javascript, momentjs

The following sections on my code are returning NaN error:
        var nextTrain = frequency - restAferLastTrain;
        var nextArrival = moment().add(nextTrain, 
I was thinking that I may need to use moment.js to compute the calculations because they are dealing with time. If so, how can I fix them?

```js
database.ref().on("child_added", function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {

  console.log(childSnapshot.val());
  //store in variables
  var trainName = childSnapshot.val().train;
  var destination =childSnapshot.val().trainOut;
  var firstTime = childSnapshot.val().trainIn;
  var frequency = childSnapshot.val().interval;


  //makes first train time neater
  var trainTime = moment.unix(firstTime).format("hh:mm");
  //calculate difference between times
  var difference =  moment().diff(moment(trainTime),"minutes");

  //time apart(remainder)
  var restAferLastTrain = difference % frequency;

  //minutes until arrival
  var nextTrain = frequency - restAferLastTrain;

  //next arrival time
  var nextArrival = moment().add(nextTrain, "minutes").format('hh:mm');
```

Comment: somewhere in your code, one of the values you think is a `number` is actually a `string`. You need to use parseInt or parseDouble on the values you retrieve from the DOM

Comment: The NaN error is at the two lines I indicated:                                   var nextTrain = frequency - restAferLastTrain;                                           and   
var nextArrival = moment().add(nextTrain,

Comment: the error read: nextTrain  is not a number and restAferLastTrain is not a number. So how can I compute them using moment.js?

Comment: Can you use the debugger or `console.log()` and show us what the values of `nextTrain` and `restAferLastTrain` are?

Comment: They return NaN